# Limit with Multivariate L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, summation

I've got the following function:

$$ f(\eta_0,\eta_1,R,T) = \frac{\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left[ 1 - (1-\eta_0R)^n - (1-\eta_1T)^n + (1-\eta_0R-\eta_1T)^n \right] P(n)}{\left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ 1-(1-\eta_0R)^n \right] P(n) \right] \left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ 1-(1-\eta_1T)^n \right] P(n) \right]}, $$

where $P(n)$ is a discrete probability distribution over $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and also $0 < R,T,\eta_0,\eta_1 < 1$, and $R+T=1$ but $\eta_{0,1}$ are not related.

I'm reading a paper which states that

$$ \lim\limits_{\eta_0,\eta_1 \to 0} f(\eta_0,\eta_1,R,T) = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)P(n)}{\left[ \sum_{n=0}^\infty nP(n) \right]^2}, $$

and they say that this can be obtained by "applying L'Hospital's Rule."

The question of multivariable versions of L'Hospital's Rule seems to be pretty complicated, so it's not clear to me what exactly the authors are referring to. It would also seem the problem is not as easy as approaching along one of the $\eta_{0,1}$ axes since setting either to zero immediately causes problems in the denominator. I tried to go along the path $\eta_0=\eta_1=\eta$ and then applying L'Hospital's rule on $\eta$, but that produced a big mess with no obvious way to simplify it down, and also that would only be the limit in a single direction, I suppose.

Any hints or ways to formally work this would be much appreciated.